# Ruby Regular Expression issue

Tags: ruby, regex

Here is my program:

```
contact_data = [
  ["joe@email.com", "123 Main st.", "555-123-4567"],
  ["sally@email.com", "404 Not Found Dr.", "123-234-3454"]
]

("Joe Smith").downcase #=> "joe smith"
contact_data[0][0].slice(0..2) #=> "joe"

("Joe Smith").downcase =~ /contact_data[0][0].slice(0..2)/ #=> nil
```

Why does my regex not show a match?

Comment: Note that you don't need parentheses around `"Joe Smith"`. When you are unsure when parentheses are needed, execute the expression without them. While not 100%, if the expression still works they probably aren't required.  Also, in case you are unaware of the different forms of [String#[\]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D), all of the following return `"joe"`: `contact_data[0][0][0..2]`, `contact_data[0][0][0...3]`, `contact_data[0][0][0,3]`,  `contact_data[0][0][/.{3}/]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot embed code inside a regular expression like that.

If that worked, how could Ruby possibly know whether this regular expression...

```
x = 3
/x/
```

... was supposed to match `3` or the literal character `x`? How *could* you write a regular expression to match a simple character `x` if you had a variable `x` defined in the local scope?

If you want to embed data inside a regular expression, you need to be much more explicit. Use `#{}` to interpolate the value as you would with a string:

```
/#{contact_data[0][0].slice(0..2)}/
```

Comment: It's worth a mention that you could use [Regexp::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-c-quote)): Regexp.new(contact_data[0][0].slice(0..2)) #=> /joe/`, or, sometimes better, [Regexp::quote](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-c-quote).